# mod_rewrite rule to remove ".php" extension and rewrite query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello i an new to Mod_Rewrite and want to use it for the first time, I have one simple request, How do i remove the .php extension from my page and rewrite querystring.

```
http://localhost/myproject/aboutus.php?page=info
http://localhost/myproject/products.php?page=first-product
```

i have multiple pages like this and what i need to do is

```
http://localhost/myproject/aboutus/info
http://localhost/myproject/products/first-product
```

Likewise aboutus.php?page=moreinfo and product.php?page=second-product and more.

All i need is a simple rule to remove the .php extension from the page and rewrite get page query string for all of my pages.
if any one can help ?

Comment: You do not want the php extension to be removed! You want it to be added to the URL so that everything "inside the server" works the way it does now. You have to change all URLs in your pages manually to remove the extension there (and yes, you'd probably need a rewrite rule to add the extension back in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess (which should be in your `myproject` directory):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_END} !^1$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)\.php$ $1/%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ $1.php?page=$2 [E=END:1,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ $1.php [E=END:1,L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [E=END:1,L]
```

Every urls, inside your `myproject` directory, matching that rule (for example `something/other-thing`) will be rewritten to `something.php?page=other-thing`

Comment: Thanks for your help the above rule work and redirect but somehow all stylesheets and javascript not working. And also some page do not have and querystring like ?page=somthing, Those are also not working without .php extension

Comment: This is a normal behaviour since your rule simulates a virtual directory. Add this in your pages right after `head` html tag: `<base href="http://localhost/myproject/" />`

Comment: Did that but same ? no css working, And also guide me for the pages which do not have ?page=somthing query like contact page is just contacts.php and after your rule its not working as localhost/myprject/contacts, and its css is gone as well

Comment: Stylesheets & javascript & images you're using in your `myproject` pages, where are they ? In your `myproject` directory ?

Comment: yes ! css in myproject/styles and javascripts in myproject/scripts

Comment: paste your style inclusion line here

Comment: css back but page is now not getting any ?page=info part it broke as it reach there. And also without ?page=somthing pages are not opening at all. Styles inclusion is like <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: some how i tried this rule and it seems to be working but just for the page i hardcode into this  RewriteRule ^aboutus/([^/]*)/?$ aboutus.php?page=$1 [L] but like this i have to write separate rules for each of my page

Comment: Do you have `Options -MultiViews` like in my answer ?

Comment: tried but its same :( well thank you for your help, I will keep looking for an answer until i get one

Comment: ok, Working now with all the pages with ?page=somthing but pages without and get page variable not opening at all

Comment: localhost/myproject/contacts This page do not have anything like aboutus?page=info its just contacts.php and i was hoping that after your rule this should open like localhost/myproject/contacts

Comment: and after you rule all pages with ?page=somthing are working like localhost/aboutus/info but only without last / if i add last slash like localhost/aboutus/info/ it also stop to work

Comment: GREAT !!!! WORKING !!! just one more thing, without querystring page which is contacts.php is working with or without last / but the pages with ?page=somthing are working without last / not with last / please solve this for me i will be realy greatfull to you

Comment: I don't get it. Could you provide an example (url you tried -> rewritten result you want) ?

Comment: after your rule now aboutus.php?page=info is working as aboutus/info but not aboutus/info/ BUT contacts.php is working as contacts and contacts/ THE LAST SLASH is not working with aboutus page and also index page is not opening without typing it like localhost/myproject/ is not opening but localhost/mypoject/index is opening

Comment: You have been really helpful, I am really great-full to you,

Comment: Just two things are left for me to work, 1. http://localhost/myproject is now showing Internal Server Error and http://localhost/myproject/index is working, 2. last  slash / not working like http://localhost/myproject/aboutus/info// but http://localhost/myproject/aboutus/info is working

Comment: localhost/myproject started to work but now all other pages working before stopped working Not Found ERROR

Comment: EXCELLENT !!!! You are genius !!! working perfectly fine everything  !! Thank you Thank you !!!

Comment: Just tell me one more thing how do i disable direct access to original php page like if someone type contacts.php or aboutus.php?page=info it should redirected to contacts and aboutus/info OR show page not found !